# Would "Seiten" be common on German websites to communicate the available web pages?

Tags: english-to-german

In the footer of our website we want have the option to select the main pages.

[image: page selection]

But the "pages" needs to be translated to the best German equivalent. The literal translation that I found was

> Seiten

But how common is that for websites?

Comment: I would take `Inhalt` (= content).

Comment: Note that “Patientfälle” as not a German word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Web context, "**Seiten**" would be the correct and common translation for "pages".

If this link list is the navigation/menu of your website, you could call it "**Navigation**" or "**Menu**"/"**Menü**".

Guntram Blohm [suggested](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/10659/1859) to use "**Links**", but I think this would typically be associated with *external* links, for example to profiles on social media sites etc.

Answer (score 2):

On the footer of a web page, I'd use the word "Links".  If you want to make a point that these are links to pages on *your* site, "Inhalt" or even "Inhaltsverzeichnis" come to mind, but normally i'd reserve these words for more or less comprehensive index pages.

Comment: "Links" as-is? I recognized that as English but it seems to also be German?

Comment: yes, Link is the correct german word for a link on a web page. See for example a court rule from 2009 which uses it: http://openjur.de/u/30720.html.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "Inhalt" or "Inhaltsverzeichnis".

Comment: You might want to make your answers a little less terse. Some explanation, that "Inhaltsverzeichnis" means "Table of content", for instance, would surely be appreciated.